# Wii Scratching Disks

Tags: nintendo-wii

I've had 3 disks broken not by the handling, but by the Wii itself.  It's a circular scratch that's pretty noticeable so I'm sure the Wii's doing it.  Replacements are costly and it takes a half of my salary to buy a new cd where I'm from so I'd really really like to know, how do you keep your Wii from doing this to your disks?

Comment: also note that **even pretty bad scratches can be fixed** by rubbing them with some brasso (brass cleaning liquid) and a lint-free cloth (microfibre works well). See here under "polish the CD": http://www.wikihow.com/Fix-a-Scratched-CD  (I fixed a few Gaemecube discs this way).

Comment: so, did it work?

Comment: I haven't found any brasso yet. Not sure to where to look for some where I live. (I'm probably looking at the wrong places) =/

Comment: I bought mine at a hardware store, but you can use some toothpastes as well. Google "fixing cd scratches" or something, there are some good solutions. Saved me hundreds of dollars.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This person](http://www.tfproject.org/tfp/tilted-gaming/119692-wii-disc-scratches-customer-service-experience.html) on the Tilted Forum Project forum seemed to get lucky with Nintendo's Customer Service. Try contacting them.

As to trying to prevent the problem, is your Wii mounted in the vertical orientation? According to some websites, placing your Wii horizontally may reduce the scratching of the discs.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to contact Nintendo Customer Support, as this seems like a hardware problem with your Wii unit itself.

During normal operation, the Wii should not scratch disks, *especially not* with a perfect circular. (unlike certain [Xbox360 Models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360_technical_problems#Scratched_discs))

Comment: Any scratch would end up being circular regardless, but the Wii definitely shouldn't be scracthing disks.